# Does assigning a new string value create garbage that needs collecting?

Tags: javascript, performance, garbage-collection

Consider this javascript code:

```
var s = "Some string";
s = "More string";
```

Will the garbage collector (GC) have work to do after this sort of operation?

(I'm wondering whether I should worry about assigning string literals when trying to minimize GC pauses.)

*e:* I'm slightly amused that, although I stated explicitly in my question that I needed to minimize GC, everyone assumed I'm wrong about that.  If one really must know the particular details: I've got a game in javascript  -- it runs fine in Chrome, but in Firefox has semi-frequent pauses, that seem to be due to GC.  (I've even checked with the MemChaser extension for Firefox, and the pauses coincide exactly with garbage collection.)

Comment: Worry about the garbage collector when you've got performance problems, and only really serious ones at that. For almost all normal pages that's the least of your worries.

Comment: While I'd want to know the answer regardless (which is why I didn't bother to mention the context), in this particular case I'm trying to improve the performance of a game engine.  This is pretty much the canonical case where you *do* need to worry about GC.

Comment: It's actually good to get an understanding of how GC works early in a project, so that you don't end up with a major refactor required down the track when you *do* have problems - and when it's much more expensive to change how you're doing things.

Comment: @starwed - Your question was sooo basic that without proper context, GC is almost never worth worrying about.  If you had included the gaming context and the observation of pauses in your original question, you would have gotten much more serious answers about GC.  But you asked such an elementary question with no context and that's why you got such elementary answers.  You shouldn't be amused about that.  More targeted questions with more context will get answers that will help you more.  That is ALWAYS true on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, strings need to be garbage-collected, just like any other type of dynamically allocated object. And yes, this is a valid concern as careless allocation of objects inside busy loops can definitely cause performance issues.

However, string values are immutable (non-changable), and most modern JavaScript implementations use "string interning", that is they store only one instance of each unique string value. This means that if you have something like this...

```
 var s1 = "abc",
     s2 = "abc";
```

...only one instance of "abc" will be allocated. This only applies to string values, not `String` objects.

A couple of things to keep in mind:

1. Functions like `substring`, `slice`, etc. will allocate a new object for each function call (if called with different parameters).
2. Even though both variable point to the same data in memory, there are still two variables to process when the GC cycle runs. Having too many local variables can also hurt you as each of them will need to be processed by the GC, adding overhead.

Some further reading on writing high-performance JavaScript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Memory_Management
- https://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript
- http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  (I'd already encountered all three of those links while searching, of course!  :) )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the garbage collector will have a string object containing `"Some string"` to get rid of.   And, in answer to your question, that string assignment will make work for the GC.

Because strings are immutable and are used a lot, the JS engine has a pretty efficient way of dealing with them.  You should not notice any pauses from garbage collecting a few strings.  The garbage collector has work to do all the time in the normal course of javascript programming.  That's how it's supposed to work.

If you are observing pauses from GC, I rather doubt it's from a few strings.  There is more likely a much bigger issue going on.  Either you have thousands of objects needing GC or some very complicated task for the GC.  We couldn't really speculate on that without study of the overall code.

This should not be a concern unless you were doing some enormous loop and dealing with tens of thousands of objects.  In that case, one might want to program a little more carefully to minimize the number of intermediate objects that are created.  But, absent that level of objects, you should first right clear, reliable code and then optimize for performance only when something has shown you that there is a performance issue to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but unless you are doing this in a loop millions of times it won't likely be a factor for you to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, JavaScript is not JavaScript. It runs on different platforms and thus will have different performance characteristics.
So the definite answer to the question "Will the GC have work to do after this sort of operation?" is: maybe. If the script is as short as you've shown it, then a JIT-Compiler might well drop the first string completely. But there's no rule in the language definition that says it has to be that way or the other way. So in the end it's like it is all too often in JavaScript: you have to try it.

The more interesting question might also be: how can you avoid garbage collection. And that is try to minimize the allocation of new objects. Games typically have a pretty constant amount of objects and often there won't be new objects until an old one gets unused. For strings this might be harder as they are immutable in JS. So try to replace strings with other (mutable) representations where possible.

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question "I'm wondering whether I should worry about assigning string literals when trying to minimize GC pauses": No.

You really don't need to worry about this sort of thing with regard to garbage collection.

GC is only a concern when creating & destroying huge numbers of Javascript objects, or large numbers of DOM elements.

Comment: This is not correct.  Strings themselves are immutable.  So the "Some String" string is an object somewhere in JS memory and it has to be removed by the GC when there are no longer any references to it.